# React useState does not seem to accept a default value here?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a chart component in which specific lines can be shown/hidden. To keep track of which lines are active I keep an `activeKeys` array in a state. Initially I get the key names from a function `getKeys` that takes the array of data.

When I do this:

```js
    const defaultValue = getKeys(data)
    console.log('defaultValue from keys', defaultValue)
    const [activeKeys, setActiveKeys] = useState(defaultValue)
    console.log('activeKeys', activeKeys)
```

First console log shows the correct keys:

```js
["createdCount", "confirmedCount", "hasFeedbackCount"]
```

Second console log shows `[]`

**But** if I do:

```js
const defaultValue = ["createdCount", "confirmedCount","hasFeedbackCount"]
console.log('defaultValue', defaultValue)
const [activeKeys, setActiveKeys] = useState(defaultValue)
console.log('activeKeys', activeKeys)
```

First console log shows the same array:

```
["createdCount", "confirmedCount", "hasFeedbackCount"]
```

**And** `activeKeys` shows the correct array:

```
["createdCount", "confirmedCount", "hasFeedbackCount"]
```

Is `useState` broken or something? By the `getKeys` is a simple function, no promise or anything like that. It looks like this:

```js
const getKeys = (data: Props['data']): string[] => {
  const reduced = data.reduce((acc, datum) => [...acc, ...Object.keys(datum.lines)] as any, [])
  const setted = new Set(reduced)
  const arrayed = Array.from(setted)
  return arrayed
}
```

The shape of `Props['data']` is:

```js
  data: {
    date: string
    lines: Partial<Record<string, number>>
  }[]
```

Comment: What is `def`? Shouldn't it be `defaultValue` instead?

Comment: @tkausl you are so fast! I edited it now, it is just a typo. In my code I wrote all of them `def` but I posted it here I wanted to make it clear by renaming it to `defaultValue`

Comment: I can't reproduce this at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-763kf . Can you share a sandbox which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Try to print data also along with default values array

Comment: @MehdiSaffar Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem. It is correct that there is not a bug with `React.useState`.

The issue here is that your component is being mounted and calculating the empty array as the default value. Subsequently your "default value" is changing to your expected default value but the `React.useState` already has a default value of empty array.

To fix this you'll need to avoid mounting the component until the desired default value is available. Alternatively you could probably do something like using a `React.useEffect` hook to look for a change in props and call the setter (second item in the array) of the `React.useState` output.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing def instead of defaultValue into useState();

```
const defaultValue = getKeys(data)
console.log('defaultValue from keys', defaultValue)
const [activeKeys, setActiveKeys] = useState(defaultValue)
console.log('activeKeys', activeKeys)
```

Comment: Sorry about this but it was typo. In my code I wrote `def` but I wanted to change it to `defaultValue` to make it clearer when posted in StackOverflow. I edited it my post.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a problem with `useState`.

As per [React DOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> **What do we pass to useState as an argument?**
>
> The only argument to the useState() Hook is the initial state. **Unlike with classes, the state doesn’t have to be an object. We can keep a number or a string if that’s all we need.** In our example, we just want a number for how many times the user clicked, so pass 0 as initial state for our variable. (If we wanted to store two different values in state, we would call useState() twice.)

So it's perfectly normal to pass an array of strings as initial state for `useState`. Even if it's the result of a function. (see snippet below).

I couldn't reproduce your `getKeys` function here on SO Snippet Editor, I suggest you further inspect that. Although this could also be a problem with the snippet builder that may not support some JS features.

NOTE: This is not a problem with `useState`. Something else is going wrong. Try to submit a working example of the issue being reproduced.

```js
function App() {
  
  const someFunction = (x) => {
    return x;
  }
  
  const data = ['A','B','C'];
  
  const [state,setState] = React.useState(someFunction(data));
  
  console.log(state);
  
  return(
    <div>{state.toString()}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```